# How can i find specific part of string in python regular expression?

Tags: python

```
case1 = http:www.freejobalert.comupsc-advt-no-18337
case2 = http:www.freejobalert.comupsc-advt-no-1833742
job_id = (''.join(re.findall(r'\d{7}:\d{5}',case1,re.I)))
```

how can i find only 33742 from this above string using regular expression .
the number maybe 5 or 7 character.

Comment: `\d{7}|\d{5}`...

Comment: thanks you..it works

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you are not using "or" (`|`), but instead a colon; Try using:

```
\d{7}|\d{5}
```

It should return the number in your string.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try something like `\d{5,7}` meaning between 5 and 7 (inclusive) digits.

`job_id = (''.join(re.search(r'(\d{5,7})',case1,re.I)))`

The default behavior will be greedy, meaning it will match as many digits as possible between 5 and 7 digits.

EDIT (Another option that may be easier to understand but will do the same thing):

`job_id = re.search(r'(\d{5,7})',case1).group(1)`

Answer (score 0):

Both the before mentioned answers are solutions to your problem, i have sumrises then as follows:

```
>>> import re
>>> case1 = "http:www.freejobalert.comupsc-advt-no-18337"
>>> case2 = "http:www.freejobalert.comupsc-advt-no-1833742"
>>> job_id1 = (''.join(re.findall(r'\d{5,7}',case1,re.I)))
>>> job_id2 = (''.join(re.findall(r'\d{5,7}',case2,re.I)))
>>> job_id1
'18337'
>>> job_id2
'1833742'

>>> job_id3 = (''.join(re.findall(r'\d{5}|\d{7}',case1,re.I)))
>>> job_id4 = (''.join(re.findall(r'\d{5}|\d{7}',case2,re.I)))
>>> job_id3
'18337'
>>> job_id4
'18337'
```